# Changing PXE preseed instructions based on desktop vs laptop?

Tags: partition, pxe, preseed

I am making a Debian 8 PXE preseed to roll out to both laptops and desktops. I would like certain commands to be run depending on whether the host is a laptop or a desktop, ie:

```
if laptop then command A
if desktop then command B
```

Is this possible? Specifically I want to set different disk partitioning schemes based on type of host.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example file [here](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/example-preseed.txt)

In particular, see the instructions at the bottom titled 'Running custom commands during the installation'. Since you can run any shell command you like inside the installer, it ought to be possible to do what you want.

Quoting examples from that page:

```
# This first command is run as early as possible, just after
# preseeding is read.
#d-i preseed/early_command string anna-install some-udeb
# This command is run immediately before the partitioner starts. It may be
# useful to apply dynamic partitioner preseeding that depends on the state
# of the disks (which may not be visible when preseed/early_command runs).
#d-i partman/early_command \
#       string debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$(list-devices disk | head -n1)"
```

Comment: But is there some way to determine whether the machine is a desktop vs a laptop to run different partitioning instructions?

Comment: Well, you probably need to think of some feature that distinguishes between laptops and desktops given the specific hardware you're dealing with (e.g. number of CPUs, hard disk size, battery capacity) and write the commands to test for that. (Search for 'linux list hardware' if you're not sure).  I don't know of any completely general test to distinguish laptops from desktops.

Comment: Thanks a million! Because the exact hardware is variable, I think I will try battery size - none of our workstations use batteries, but of course all of our laptops do.